# Is it really a bad practice to use SQL from client side application (where the end-client own the database)

Tags: sql-server, flutter

My company make Point Of Sell and Accounting systems.
each client (being a restaurant or supermarket) have a server machine on the local network, that have MS SQL, so all cashiers applications connects to it.
However when we migrated to Flutter, it is difficult to connect to MS SQL server (especially on the web platform).
And when I read about it, it always about that this is a bad practice and imposes a security issues, and the correct way to do it is using an API.
I don't see how that would be a bad solution for my problem, and making an API would just complicate a lot of things.
So I have two Questions:

1. Is it still a bad practice in my situations, if so, is an API the only best solution?
2. If it's fine to do it that way, how do I connect to MS SQL server using flutter in the web platform.

For Android platform in flutter, I did use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn) package.
and it works fine, however I was not able to find such package that supports web.

Comment: If they have a local server, i don't see why you need API? API is when you have a remote sql server and some clients that need data from it. But sure, API would allow you to easier move the server out :)

Comment: @siggemannen even if the server is remote, the access to it would still be limited using authentication with credentials that only the database owner would have, right ? i don't see why API would be necessary. (assuming the cashiers applications is secured enough along side the machines that runs them)

Comment: it's just that sql server was designed to use in LAN, not over WAN, so the performance might be much worse doing direct access

Comment: plus, most admins don't like to open sql server servers to outsiders

Comment: Yeah, it's still bad practice. Not only from a security point of view (which *might* eventually be a minor issue in your usecase) but also from the point of maintainability

Answer (score 1):

> Is it still a bad practice in my situations, if so, is an API the only best solution ?.

An API is definitely a safer way to go. SQL gives a lot of power to the end user to delete things, or steal all the data. For that reason I'd consider this approach bad practice.

There are ways to mitigate the issues that come up but it requires being a SQL expert. For instance you can use sql to control individual user permissions e.g `grant execute on table1 to user blah` or you could write sql functions to limit what sql the users can run. This can prevent them deleting all the records.

However some things are more tricky, like denial of service, or running a painfully slow query on some unindexed field causing it to hang. Or locking a record for editing forever. These gottchas are what make it bad practice.

You can use certificate based logins and things, but all in all, the easiest way to secure the system is to tighten access to the network. Use a separate wired network with VLAN separation and ensure it's not easy for someone to plug a cable into an unsecured access point.

Whether I'd rewrite it to use an API or buy something better off the shelf depends on quite how big this product is.